# Detect configuration changes in onStop() method without using isChangingConfigurations()

Tags: java, android, api, android-activity

Currently I'm writing Android app using API level 10. I need to detect configuration changes (Screen rotation) in `onStop()` method. I cannot use `isChangingConfigurations()` method because it is only available in API level 11 or above.

How can I detect configuration changes manually in `onStop()` method?

Answer (score -1):

can you please explain more deeply your question because I cannot see the case here...I mean onStop() as you can read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop() is called when your activity is no longer visible for the user. It could be never called also. So I cannot see how  your are going to detect any UI behavior when your activity is gone.

If you want to detect some UI behavior you need to declare that in the android:configChanges attribute in your activity declaration in manifest. You can see docs here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

In your case (Screen Rotation) you will need android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout" 
orientation handle screen rotation in prehoneycomb devices and screenLayout for the rest.

So when you declare that in your activity element and rotate your device the onConfigurationChanged() method (that you should override) will be called and you can perform your operation inside it. The activity itself will not be recreate and onCreate() wont be called.

Comment: Actually I need to check in onStop(), whether the activity is in the process of being destroyed in order to be recreated with a new configuration. In API level 11, I can use isChangingConfigurations() method, but in API level 10, I cannot use it.